# Multiple parameters are not being send properly in get method using Angular 5 and Node js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, get

I am trying to create a API using nodejs and access it using GET method by sending parameters using Angular 5 GET method. When I am testing my API using Postman, it works fine, but sending the GET request from Angular is not giving me the result. My node js router for receiving multiple parameters code is as follow:

```
router.get('/:min&:max',(req,res,next)=> {
    Image.find({hue: {$gt:req.params.min,$lt:req.params.max}})
        .select('name url hue')
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            const response={
                images: docs.map(doc=> {
                    return {
                        name: doc.name,
                        url: doc.url,
                        hue: doc.hue,
                        _id: doc._id,
                    }
                })
            }
            res.status(200).json(docs);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
})
```

My angular GET method goes like this :

```
getSearchedImages(min, max) {
        let params = {
            'min': String(min),
            'max': String(max)
        }
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/', { params: params})
            .subscribe(val=> console.log(val))
    }
```

Is there any problem in Angular part or is my code in Node is to be adjusted

Answer (score 1):

Use POST if you want to pass parameters in request body. Otherwise, if you like GET, pass parameters in URL.

HTTP itself doesnt restrict this, but some front-end implementations do

Comment: Is it a good practise to send the parameters in url like : this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/'+min+'&'+max)

Comment: It's absolutely ok. Just dont forget to properly encode them if special characters may appear. Also some security issues may be taken into consideration because proxy and other intermediate servers may log urls but not the body of the message.